# SQL Server: update column with only numbers from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a string in column X that has a mixture of text and numbers. I need to extract those numbers and place them into another column so that I can easily query on it. The field always has ABC and number within it, but those characters could be anywhere in the string, for example column X could include:

```
 ABC 123456 blah blah 
 ABC 234567 blah 555-01234
 ABC:345678 something else 012
 the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog ABC456789
```

I'd then like to update column Y to include only the first set of numerics (not all numerics in the string), so I'm expecting:

```
 123456 
 234567
 345678
 456789
```

Can this be done? I've read about using `PATINDEX`, but I can't work out how to incorporate this into an update query like:

```
update table1 set y = x where x like '%ABC%'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `stuff()`, `left()`, and `patindex()` to find the start and end of the first set of numbers:

```
update t
  set num = left(stuff(str,1,patindex('%[0123456789]%',str)-1,'')
       , patindex('%[^0123456789]%'
         , stuff(str,1,patindex('%[0123456789]%',str)-1,'')+' ')-1
       )

select * 
from t
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/DUE94933

returns:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|                          str                          |  num   |
+-------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| ABC 123456 blah blah                                  | 123456 |
| ABC 234567 blah 555-01234                             | 234567 |
| ABC:345678 something else 012                         | 345678 |
| the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog ABC456789 | 456789 |
+-------------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks for that. This is almost perfect for what I need, but in my test data I get a trailing '-' in some rows. For example the data 'ABC-123456-blah' returns '123456-' rather than '123456'. Any idea how I can tweak the query to remove the final '-'?

Comment: @SteveA sorry, forgot the `-1` after the second `patindex()`.   Answer corrected.